# Upload only modified files to FTP server

Tags: linux, sync, ftp

I want to upload files from my computer to an FTP site and I don't want to upload files that are already on the server. So I need a tool that finds out which local files that are different from the ones on the server, or that don't exists on the server.

Some requirements:

- I'm using a cheap provider that does not support rsync or ssh, so I can only use FTP.
- I generate the files before uploading them, so comparing timestamps is meaningless.
- I've tried lftp with the mirror command. It's slow (I think it uploads all the files).
- I upload the files from different computers, so I can't use [sitecopy](http://www.manyfish.co.uk/sitecopy/), which uses a local database to keep track of which files are on the server.
- I'd like to be able to upload all changed files with one command. Preferably no GUI application. And it needs to run in Ubuntu.

I was thinking about creating a tool similar to sitecopy, but which stores checksums of all the files on the FTP server on the server itself. But then I thought that there may already be such a tool.

Comment: BTW, does this belong on serverfault instead?

Comment: You might want to take a look at the answers to this question on ServerFault: http://serverfault.com/questions/24622/how-to-use-rsync-over-ftp

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried **filezilla**?

Has a "Directory Comparison" feature that may be what you are looking for.

Comment: Uhm, this question is over 5 years old, and the OP hasn't been logged in to the site for over a year. Why try to revive this now? :P

Comment: The question is not only of interest for the OP but also for others such as myself.